# Copy pdfs in a directory to folders with the same name as the PDFs

Tags: python, pdf, directory

I want to put the pdfs I have in a directory in to the folders with the same name. Those folders with the same name have already been created and are in the same directory as the pdf files I want to move in to them.

I am relatively new at python and have not gotten very far on the code. Currently when I run the below it only prints the .pdf files but does not print the subfolders within the directory (that is besides the point but I am not sure why I cant see the sub folders in the directory in the below code.)

```
import os
from shutil import copyfile

path_to_files = "C:\\tmp\\all_files_converted\\"

def copy_documents(file_path):

    for f in os.listdir(file_path):
        print(f)


copy_documents(path_to_files)
```

[folders in directory C://tmp//all_files_converted//](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Hsn9.png)

[pdf files with the same name as the folders in the same directory C://tmp//all_files_converted//](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ByUvL.png)

Comment: Could this be any file, or does it matter that it's a pdf? Why is the question tagged [tag:pdf]?

Comment: All files in the directory are and always will be pdf files. I am open to a more general solution to all file types but figured having a solution tailored specifically to pdf files will provide a specific solution and possible shortcuts, where I do not have to write a lot of lines of code to capture all file types.

Comment: You need to join together the directory and the filename: `print(os.path.join(file_path, f))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `pathlib` and `shutil` to perform this:

```py
from pathlib import Path
from shutil import move

path_to_files = Path(r"C:\tmp\all_files_converted")
for pdf_path in path_to_files.glob("*.pdf"):
    dir_path = path_to_files / pdf_path.stem
    dir_path.mkdir()
    move(pdf_path, dir_path / pdf_path.name)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `shutil.move(src, dst)`

```
import shutil  

shutil.move(src, dst)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import os
from shutil import copyfile
from glob import glob

path_to_files = "pasta"


def copy_documents(path_to_files):
    # os.path is a module to work with file paths
    # Using the module glob to list all pdf files of a folder
    for file_path in glob(os.path.join(path_to_files, "*.pdf")):
        # basename will return the filename without the rest of the path ie: "something.pdf"
        pdf_file_name = os.path.basename(file_path)
        dest_folder = os.path.join(path_to_files, pdf_file_name[:-4])
        print(f"Copy {file_path} to {dest_folder}")
        copyfile(file_path, os.path.join(dest_folder, pdf_file_name))

copy_documents(path_to_files)
```

I recommend reading https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html and https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html

for more info.

Comment: thank you for your descriptive answer! I was able to move them to the correct folder! :) I appreciate the help and the additional links to keep learning!